# Meager subset of $2^\omega$

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category

Suppose we do have a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $\omega$ which contains the cofinite filter, so $X\in\mathcal{F}$ implies $X$ is infinite. For $X\in\mathcal{F}$, let $f_X$ be the increasing enumeration of $X$. Let $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}=\{f_X\mid X\in\mathcal{F}\}$. Let $f\in\omega^\omega$ s.t. $f$ is a bound of $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$.

Identify $X\subseteq\omega$ with $x\in2^\omega$ defined by $x(n)=1$ if $n\in X$ and $x(n)=0$, if $n\notin X$ and consider the discrete topology on $2$ and the product topology in $2^\omega$.

I want to prove, that $A_n:=\{X\subseteq\omega\mid\forall k\geq n\ f_X(k)\leq f(k)\}$ is meager for all $n\in\omega$. Any hints?

Definition of an unbounded familiy $F$: A family of subsets of $\omega^\omega$ is unbounded, if for all $g\in \omega^\omega$ exists a $f\in F$ s.t. $\neg(f\leq^* g)$, where $f\leq^*g$ means $f(n)\leq g(n)$ for all but finitely many $n\in\omega$.

Comment: Meager in what space and what topology exactly? Clearly the space is not $\omega$, but it seems not to be $\omega^\omega$ either.

Comment: In $2^\omega$ with discrete Topology in 2 and product Topology.

Comment: One can identify a subset $X\subseteq\omega$ with $x\in2^\omega$ defined by $x(n)=1$ if $n\in X$ and $x(n)=0$, if $n\notin X$.

Comment: Yes, I know. You should clarify this in your question.

Comment: It's not clear to me that such $f$ exists. Why should it exist?

Comment: But the existence is not important for the proof. It is an assumption.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, then.

Comment: Maybe it is also the topology generated by the basis $\{[s]:s\in 2^{<\omega}\}$

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $\mathcal{F}$ is a red herring; the real question is

> For $f\in\omega^\omega$ unbounded, show that $A_f:=\{X: \forall k, f_X(k)\le f(k)\}$  is meager.

Note that I've also gotten rid of $n$; this is just for simplicity, and won't change anything important.

EXERCISE: for every $\sigma\in 2^{<\omega}$ there is some $\tau\in 2^{<\omega}$ with $\sigma\preccurlyeq\tau$ such that for any $X$, if the characteristic function of $X$ extends $\tau$, then $X$ is not in $A_f$.

If you can do this, do you see why this means $A_f$ is in fact nowhere dense (not just meager)? (The passage to meager comes when we bring $n$ back into the picture.)

---

By the way, this line of attack comes from the *game picture* of category; see e.g. my answer to [Analogy for Baire categories?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717561/analogy-for-baire-categories).

Comment: f unbounded means that one cannot find a M s.t. $f\leq M$ and $\sigma\preccurlyeq\tau$ means $\sigma$ is extended by $\tau$?

Comment: Let $n$ be the number of $1$'s in the finite sequence $\sigma$. Then, if the chracteristic function $\chi_X$ of a $X\subseteq\omega$ extends $\sigma$, $f_X(n)$ denotes the n-th element in X (ordering $<$. Then one can define $\tau$ as $\tau(i)=\sigma(i)$ for $i=0,...,|\sigma|$ and $\tau(i)=0$ sufficently many $i>|\sigma|$ s.t. the element $f_X(n+1)$ must be greater than $f(n+1)$, if the characteristic function extends $\tau$, hence $X\notin A_f$.

Comment: But i am not able to see why thiis mean $A_f$ is nowhere dense (in what topology?)

Comment: @peer Such a $\tau$ determines an open set (in the usual topology on Cantor space, generated by finite strings) in which $A_f$ has no element (since no function extending $\tau$ lies in $A_f$). Moreover, what we've shown is that for *every* $\sigma$, there is such a $\tau$ extending $\sigma$. Think about finite strings as basic open sets: what this means is that, for every open set $U$ in Cantor space, there is some smaller open set $V$ such that $A_f\cap V=\emptyset$. This is exactly the definition of "nowhere dense."

Comment: To clarify: the topology on Cantor space used here is the standard one, generated by the sets of the form $\{r: \rho\prec r\}$ for $\rho\in 2^{<\omega}$ (these basic opens are sometimes called *cylinders*). As to the game picture mentioned at the end of my answer: consider the following game between two players, I and II. They alternately play finite strings of $0$s and $1$s, and I wins if the infinite string they produce (after infinitely many moves) lies in $A_f$. Clearly II has a winning strategy; it turns out that this means that the payoff set (in this case, $A_f$) is meager!

Comment: I know the following definition of nowhere dense: A set $A$ is nowhere dense, if $Int(\overline{A})=\emptyset$. However, this is equivalent to $X\backslash\overline{A}$ is dense which is equivalent to $(X\backslash\overline{A})\cap U$ for every $x\in X$ and every neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: @peer Well, the equivalence of that definition with the one I gave above is a good exercise. HINT for one direction: suppose $Int(\overline{A})\not=\emptyset$. Can you find an open nonempty $U$ such that there is *no* open nonempty $V\subseteq U$ with $V\cap A=\emptyset$? The other direction is similar.

Comment: And finally i use that $A_f$ is meager and hence, $A_n$ (defined in my first post is) is meager since $A_n\subseteq A_f$ (subsets of meager sets are meager)?

Comment: @peer That's not right: $A_f$ is just $A_0$, and in general $A_{n+1}$ will be a *superset* of $A_n$. You need to look at the argument above, and generalize it a little bit to handle arbitrary $A_n$s. (HINT: count the initial segments of length $n$ . . .)

Comment: Well, i can consider the finite sequences $s\in 2^{<\omega}$ of length $|s|=n$ and consider the $2^n$ subtrees of $2^{<\omega}$ which can be reached by the finite sequences. In each of these subtrees, i can define the set $A_f^{(i)}$, which is nowhere dense. And the set $A_n$ is the union of the sets $A_f^{(i)}$ concateneted with the initial segment, hence meager. Is this the correct idea?