# Baire property and $F_\sigma$ sets

Tags: general-topology

I am currently reading a proof for a theorem which concludes that a set A does not have the Baire property, if (1) is correct. So, $(1)\Rightarrow$A does not have the Baire property is shown. The proof is by contradiction and starts like this: Let $F=\cup_{n\in\omega}F_n$ be any meager set of type $F_\sigma$. My question is, if every set which does have the Baire property is a $F_\sigma$ set and if the converse statement does hold .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every $F_\sigma$ set has the property of Baire; however, the converse is extremely false. Indeed, every **Borel set** (even every analytic or co-analytic set) has the property of Baire, and $F_\sigma$ sets represent only the first two levels of the Borel hierarchy, which has uncountably many levels.

It doesn't stop there, either. For example, it is consistent with ZF+DC (assuming large cardinals are consistent) that **every** set has the property of Baire. A way to bring this into the ZFC-world is: it follows from large cardinals that every set of reals in $L(\mathbb{R}$) has the property of Baire ($L(\mathbb{R})$ is a bit technical; roughly, this means that any set you can define in terms of real numbers has the property of Baire - in particular, every set you've ever heard of is in $L(\mathbb{R})$).

---

By the way, although it doesn't seem material to your actual question: what is property (1)?

Comment: The set A is a filter on $\omega$ and the filter can be considered as a subset of $2^\omega$ as stated in my question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842206/meager-subset-of-2-omega. (1) actually is the following statement: For every partition $\{I_n:n\in\omega\}$of $\omega$ into finite sets, there exists $X\in\mathcal{F}$ s.t. $X\cap I_n=\emptyset$ for infinitely many $n\in\omega$.

Comment: But then, i don't understand the proof. The author should have started like this: Suppose $A$ does have the Baire property... This is a contradiction to ...

Comment: Re: your second comment, I can't comment on the proof without seeing more of it. But if you're trying to prove that $A$ **does** have the Baire property by contradiction, then you do **not** start out by assuming it *does* - you assume it *doesn't*. (Or was that a typo?) Can you give a link to the proof you're reading?

Comment: I am trying to proof that A does not have the Baire property. The proof can be found in chapter 4.1 as Theorem 2 in the book Set theory  on the structure of the real line by Bartoszynski. Shall i add it here?

Comment: @peer Well, I answered the question you asked in this post. If you want me or others to help with a specific proof, then yes, you should post that proof here.

Comment: Concerning my first comment: you asked for (1) in your answer.